# How to do you split a range string to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, split

i can run in sql server for this but i get only width column( w_pacakaging) , but i dont know to write get value length or high from column  Packing list text

```
DATA    Packing list text    W_packaging          Length        High                  
          38"x45"x44"           38
```

my code is

```
select [Packing list text],[Grade],[sales doc no], 
 case when [Packing list text] like'%:%' then 
  cast(Ltrim(Rtrim(SUBSTRING([Packing list text], charindex(':', [Packing list text]) + 1, charindex('"', [Packing list text])  

  - (charindex(':', [Packing list text]) + 1)))) as [nvarchar] ) 
                       END AS [W_packaging] 
 from [TPC_CRSYS].[dbo].[TotalOrder_Export]
```

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77siZ.jpg)

the result show i can only split range to width, but length and High column i dont know how write code to split it . Is there a way to split the number of range to Length and High?

Comment: Your sample text has no colon.  Why is that in your code?

Comment: Which version of SQL-Server? With 2016 there is native string split support...

Comment: i use sql version 2008, Is there a way to split the number of range to Length and High?

Answer (score 0):

This approach allows you to extract your dimensions type safe:

As first step I cut the string at the `:` and do some string action with the rest. The `26"x36"x42"` is changed to `<x>26</x><x>36</x><x>42</x>`. This is XML and can be easily queried with `.value()`. The `int` as second parameter returns a typed int value...

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(100)='@ 21 REAMS x 24 PAELLETSDIMENSION (WXLXH):26"x36"x42"';

WITH MyDimenstions AS
( 
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@s,CHARINDEX(':',@s)+1,1000),'"x','</x><x>'),'"','')+'</x>' AS XML) AS Dims
)
SELECT Dims.value('/x[1]','int') AS [Width] 
      ,Dims.value('/x[2]','int') AS [Length]
      ,Dims.value('/x[3]','int') AS [Height]
FROM MyDimenstions
```

The result

```
Width   Length  Height
26      36      42
```

### UPDATE

I understand your comment, that you don't know how to translate this approach to table based data. Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(s VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('@ 21 REAMS x 24 PAELLETSDIMENSION (WXLXH):26"x36"x42"')
,('@ 22 REAMS x 42 PAELLETSDIMENSION (WXLXH):1"x11"x111"');

WITH MyDimenstions AS
( 
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(s,CHARINDEX(':',s)+1,1000),'"x','</x><x>'),'"','')+'</x>' AS XML) AS Dims
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT Dims.value('/x[1]','int') AS [Width] 
      ,Dims.value('/x[2]','int') AS [Length]
      ,Dims.value('/x[3]','int') AS [Height]
FROM MyDimenstions
```

Comment: the code is wonderful,but if i want  @s VARCHAR(100) from  select [Packing list text] from [dbo].[TotalOrder_Export] ,Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: It ok @Shnugo  but i have another  problem  if i want to count (x) in each row in my db(have 10,000 rows) that shown it below                                                                                                                                                [data :  X  " X  "  , 400 REMS x 946 PALLETS1 ,32"x44"x42"                      result :    2          ,                   1                         ,       3                                                                                                           
       Is there anyway to count and get count  number of x?

Comment: Hi @monte, as you are new here (Btw: Welcome!) please allow me one hint: It is one principle on SO to keep the issues tightly separated. One problem, one solution. Your *another problem* is a new issue. So: Close **this question** by ticking the acceptance check below the answer's vote counter. Then start a new question for your new issue and place a link here. I'll come there soon. Advantages: New questions pull more attraction, points for you and me, better hits for followers searching for similar problems. Thx and Happy Coding!